# How to mock Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Before anything else I want to clarify that I'm asking about `Firebase Realtime Database` and not `Firestore`.

**Background:**

I have an app that uses both Firestore and Firebase Realtime database. I've found a way to unit test Firestore by mocking it using the [cloud firestore mocks package](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_mocks) at dart pub. So far I've been trying to search if there were any equivalents for Firebase Realtime Database and I haven't seen any. Both here and Google..

So my question is, how would one be able to create a unit test that needs a Mock of a FirebaseDatabase instance? similar to how you could do it in the mock firestore package so that I can do something like:

```dart
MockDbInstance mockFirebaseDatabaseInstance = MockFirebaseDatabaseInstance();
await mockFirebaseDatabaseInstance.reference().child("this_node").setValue(myObject);
```

**Update:**

We couldn't find a way to easily test RTDB so we decided to move all our data to FireStore.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a solution to this we just ended up using Firestore all the way.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [fireabase_database_mocks](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database_mocks) package which mock firebase **real time database** but it is incomplete it does not support the simulation of events
like onChildAdded for now but it's doable. Here is an example of using [fireabase_database_mocks](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database_mocks) :

```dart
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database_mocks/firebase_database_mocks.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class UserRepository {
  UserRepository(this.firebaseDatabase);
  FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

  Future<String> getUserName(String userId) async {
    final userNameReference =
        firebaseDatabase.reference().child('users').child(userId).child('name');
    final dataSnapshot = await userNameReference.once();
    return dataSnapshot.value;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUser(String userId) async {
    final userNode = firebaseDatabase.reference().child('users/$userId');
    final dataSnapshot = await userNode.once();
    return dataSnapshot.value;
  }
}

void main() {
  FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
  UserRepository userRepository;
  // Put fake data
  const userId = 'userId';
  const userName = 'Elon musk';
  const fakeData = {
    'users': {
      userId: {
        'name': userName,
        'email': 'musk.email@tesla.com',
        'photoUrl': 'url-to-photo.jpg',
      },
      'otherUserId': {
        'name': 'userName',
        'email': 'othermusk.email@tesla.com',
        'photoUrl': 'other_url-to-photo.jpg',
      }
    }
  };
  MockFirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().set(fakeData);
  setUp(() {
    firebaseDatabase = MockFirebaseDatabase.instance;
    userRepository = UserRepository(firebaseDatabase);
  });
  test('Should get userName ...', () async {
    final userNameFromFakeDatabase = await userRepository.getUserName(userId);
    expect(userNameFromFakeDatabase, equals(userName));
  });

  test('Should get user ...', () async {
    final userNameFromFakeDatabase = await userRepository.getUser(userId);
    expect(
      userNameFromFakeDatabase,
      equals({
        'name': userName,
        'email': 'musk.email@tesla.com',
        'photoUrl': 'url-to-photo.jpg',
      }),
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for sharing this.